# msmtp sendmail substitutions don't work (%U etc.)

Tags: msmtp

I'm running msmtp 1.8.3-1 on Debian buster, and it's configured and everything works except the sendmail substitutions.

I have a `from %U@myhost.mydomain.com`  line in my `/etc/msmtprc` file but I can't seem to get it to work.

The documents talk about sendmail mode: how do I tell if that's enabled? My system has a symlink from `/sbin/sendmail` to `../bin/msmtp`  and running `/sbin/sendmail` does get an email out as expected. But there's no difference in how that works vs. `msmtp` from the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with msmtp version 1.8.3 on Debian 10 (Buster).

My workaround was to set the *obsolete* configuration settings:

```
auto_from on
maildomain myhost.mydomain.com
```

in `/etc/msmtprc`

https://marlam.de/msmtp/msmtp.html#Commands-specific-to-sendmail-mode

This is more or less the same as `from %U@myhost.mydomain.com`.